# Having trouble specifying and splitting Pandas dataframes to modifying them separately

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to split a pandas dataframe from a single index into multiple by splitting each column into its own index if it contains a " ; ". I have found a way to successfully achieve what I want in small scale, but I know I need a better solution for when I move it into my main project.

```py
import pandas as pd 

input_values = [['1;3', '2;5', '3;7']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(input_values, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

data1 = pd.DataFrame(input_values, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(input_values, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

for column in columns:
    new = df[column].str.split(";", expand = True)
    data1[column] = new[0]
    data2[column] = new[1]

df = data1.merge(data2, how='outer')
# df print
print('\n', df)
```

Which gives the output that I am looking for:

```py
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  5  7
```

My current problem is that I want df = data1 = data2 without having to specify each separately as I've done in my solution.

What is the better solution that I know I have overlooked? I'm looking for a way to specify my dataframe once and then set other variables equal to it.

Ex of what I want to have (this does not work however as each dataframe is updating together):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(input_values, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

data1 = df
data2 = df
```

Thanks for your time and input, hopefully I'm not overlooking something too simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the following works for you:

```
df                                                                                                                        
#Out[266]: 
#     a    b    c
#0  1;3  2;5  3;7

df.T[0].str.split(';', expand=True).T                                                                                     
#Out[267]: 
#   a  b  c
#0  1  2  3
#1  3  5  7
```

Comment: Thanks man, It is truly amazing how you can so effortlessly turn 15 lines into one. That works fantastically. I'll have to look into it more to see why it works

Answer (score 0):

You can split columns in a list comprehension and concatenate the results:

```
pd.concat([df[x].str.split(";", expand=True).stack() 
          for x in df], axis=1).loc[0]
#   0  1  2
#0  1  2  3
#1  3  5  7
```

And an even more efficient solution:

```
df.T[0].str.split(";", expand=True).T
#   a  b  c
#0  1  2  3
#1  3  5  7
```